# why segmentation error in my program

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int num[5], i, s, no;
    for(i=0; i<5 ;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&num[i]);
    }
    printf("enter a number\n");
    scanf("%d", &no);
    s=search(no, &num[0]);
    printf("%d\n",s);
    search1(no,num);
}

int i=0;

int search(int no,int *num[i])
{
    int x,i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        if(no == *num[i])
        return 1;
    }
    return 0; 
}

int search1(int no,int *num)    
{ 
    int i,x,k; 
    printf("your number %d is present in the list",no);
    printf("number\tfrequency");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(x=0;x<i+1;x++)
        {
            k=0;
            if(num[i]==num[x] &&i!=x)
            {
                k=0;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                k=1;
                continue;
            }
        }
        if(k==1) {
            printf("%d",num[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

This question is based on passing an array to function. My code is compiling but at run-time after asking for input number, to check its presence in the list, it shows segmentation error.

Comment: You have a global variable `i`, and you have a lot of local variables `i`, which completely hide the global variable.  That is not good.

Comment: It is very difficult for another human to read your code. Please adopt an accepted formatting style, before you ever write ***one*** more line of code. In my view, the way you present your code reflects the way you are thinking: haphazard fomattting ~ random approach to the solution.

Comment: ... perhaps your thoughts are ahead of your typing, but another advantage of a rigid formatting style is that it allows you time to consider and review those thoughts, as you prepare the code.

Comment: @WeatherVane I edited his question waiting for approve... there are multiple problems with his code.

Comment: @TonyTannous approved.

Answer (score 0):

Change your search function declaration to:

```
int search(int no,int *num)
```

Change the way you access to the array elements:

```
if (no == num[i]) // Instead of *num[i]
```

and call it like:

```
s=search(no,num)
```

I think you have some confusion about arrays, pointers and argument passing.
Also, as comments below your question already point out, you should adopt a better coding style. Your code is really hard to read.

This may be a good start point:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/process/coding-style.rst